# Wordpress - Edit dashboard page on plugin activation

Tags: php, wordpress

I found a piece of code on David Walsh's [post](http://davidwalsh.name/add-profile-fields) about adding Custom fields on user contact form. But that is done in function.php. I want the same to be done when my plugin gets activated. I found out that it is difficult to invoke add_filter on activation hook and found out another snippet on wordpress documentation. I merged them and tried this following piece of code but my plugin installation is getting failed. I know something is wrong but can't find out what.

```
<?php
function modify_contact_methods($profile_fields) {

// Add new fields
$profile_fields['twitter'] = 'Twitter Username';
$profile_fields['facebook'] = 'Facebook URL';
$profile_fields['gplus'] = 'Google+ URL';

// Remove old fields
unset($profile_fields['aim']);

return $profile_fields;
}

/* Main Plugin File */
function my_plugin_activate() {

    add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'modify_contact_methods');
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_activate' );

function load_plugin() {

if ( is_admin() && add_filter('user_contactmethods' ) == 'modify_contact_methods' ) {

    delete_option( 'Activated_Plugin' );

    /* do stuff once right after activation */
    // example: add_action( 'init', 'my_init_function' );
}
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'load_plugin' );
```

Comment: Hi, you wanted to work after plugin activated, but it works for once after activated. You need to make a simple plugin that contains function for filter `user_contactmethods`. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make it work after your plugin activated and work forever after activated, you can use following;

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Simple Plugin
Plugin URI: http://huseyinbabal.net
Description: Simple plugin
Version: 0.1
Author: Hsüseyin BABAL
Author URI: http://huseyinbabal.net
*/
function modify_contact_methods($profile_fields) {

// Add new fields
$profile_fields['twitter'] = 'Twitter Username';
$profile_fields['facebook'] = 'Facebook URL';
$profile_fields['gplus'] = 'Google+ URL';

// Remove old fields
unset($profile_fields['aim']);

return $profile_fields;
}

add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'modify_contact_methods');
```